# DropdownListFor in Razor form from datatable based on user

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, razor-pages

I need a little help with this dropdown list. I have a form that I would like the customer's location to be a select item. I have a view model that populates everything I need but would like to make the location selectable. Each customer should have at least 1 entry so in my view I will probably need to get a count with an "if" statement, before populating a dropdown and if there is only 1 then just use that as an EditorFor. Location is being pulled from an addresses table along with Customer name being pulled from a Customer table.

I have tried doing a

```
ViewBag.Locations = new SelectList(db.Addresses, "AddressId", "LocationName");
```

However the current Model setup grabs from the Addresses table and the column is not an IEnumerable SelectList. Below is my model:

```
public class AddEventViewModel
{
    public static AddEventViewModel GetCustomerInfo(string userId, CustomerEntities db)
    {
        var QCustInfo = from ad in db.Addresses
                        join ua in db.UserToAddresses on ad.AddressId equals ua.AddressId
                        join cus in db.CustomerNames on ad.CustomerId equals cus.CustomerId
                        where (ua.UserId == userId)
                        select new AddEventViewModel
                        {
                            CustomerId = cus.CustomerId,
                            CustomerName = cus.CustomerName,
                            Location = ad.LocationName
                        };
        var result = QCustInfo.SingleOrDefault();

        return result;
    }

    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Location Name")]
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public bool AllDay { get; set; }
    [Display(Name ="Title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime), Required]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/mm/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [Display(Name = "Start Date")]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime), Required]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/mm/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [Display(Name = "End Date")]
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Customer Name")]
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }

    public virtual CustomerNames Customer { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<Addresses> Addresses { get; set; }
```

The form is just a basic form with fields and works I just need the location to be selectable. Making another viewModel doesn't seem to be the way with my current setup as it is making joins with the actual table model. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So turns out that all I needed to do was add.

```
new SelectList(Model.Addresses, "AddressId", "LocationName"),
```

To the Html.DropdownListFor 
Code at top did not change. Here is the full string.

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Location, new SelectList(Model.Addresses, "AddressId", "LocationName"), new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```